# Are both sentences idiomatic and same in meaning: 1-John got the nearest. 2-John came the closest

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning, idiomatic-language

One person is describing something to other three people, and the other 3 are trying to guess what it is. But, in one case, after the description, all three showed their answers written on paper, but no answer was right. However one of them was quite close to the answer.

So, here is the conversation between these people after the description:

**A: Who got it right?**

**B: John came the closest.**

But, in another part of the conversation, I also heard  **"John got the nearest."**, which was used for the same circumstance. So, both sentences seemed the same to me in meaning, but I can't make sure if they are both idiomatic.

So, I wondered do both sentences sound idiomatic?

Comment: I think you've effectively answered your own question, simply by the fact that you wrote *one of them **was** quite **close** to the answer* (as opposed to *...was quite **near** the answer* or ***...got / came** close*).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All these variations are perfectly idiomatic, and mean exactly the same thing...

> 1: *John came the closest*
> 2: *John came the nearest*
> 3: *John came closest*
> 4: *John came nearest*
> 5: *John was the closest*
> 6: *John was the nearest*
> 7: ***John was closest***  **<=== my preferred version**
> 8: *John was nearest*
> 9: *John got the closest*
> 11: *John got the nearest*
> 12: *John got closest*
> 13: *John got nearest*
> 14: *John's answer was nearest*
> ...

[Here](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=answer%20is%20closest%2Canswer%20is%20nearest&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=10) and [here](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=closest%20answer%2Cnearest%20answer&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=10) are a couple of usage charts clearly showing that we nearly always used figurative ***nearest*** a century ago. By the 1970s we'd switched to ***closest,*** but they're both essentially the same "spatial proximity" metaphor, referencing ***degree of similarity** [to the **correct** answer]*.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, both are idiomatic and they mean the same. The only possible difference is that "John got the nearest" could have an unspoken direct object, e.g. "John got the nearest answer". The other could also, but less directly, e.g. "John got the closest to ...".

Comment: I don't think there are any relevant differences in the "syntactic affordances" of ***closest, nearest*** in this particular figurative usage. But as it happens, [***the closest answer*** is currently far more common than ***the nearest answer***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+closest+answer%2Cthe+nearest+answer&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3), which appears to contradict what you say.

Comment: @FumbleFingers also "**came** the closest" [is far more common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=came+the+closest%2Cgot+the+closest%2C+came+the+nearest%2C+got+the+nearest&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) than any of the others.

Comment: @BillyKerr: Not exactly! "**was** the closest" is [far more common than all the other verbs put together](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=came+the+closest%2Cgot+the+closest%2Ccame+the+nearest%2Cgot+the+nearest%2Cwas+the+closest&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) (and that's my preferred form).

Comment: "came" and "got" imply movement, whereas "was" implies state ... so there is a subtle difference in nuance, although they are as good as interchangeable in practice. "got closest/nearest" is probably most colloquial, but maybe less common in written text.